# Passing a filepath through a loop in a Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I'm using the 'list folder' connector to list all the files in a SharePoint folder. 
I then use a for each row to loop through all the individual files in the SharePoint folder. The point is I want to extract a table in the file to a CSV table and then save this to blob storage.

Please find a picture of the current setup:

[Image of setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os6bw.png)

[image]

When I run the app I get the following error:

> BadRequest. Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON.

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRu7y.png)

[image]

Display of the code:

[View of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KB1Pp.png)

[image]

I have tried various methods, including converting to string, JSON and encoding to URI.

How can I solve this issue?

Error code output:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "headers": {
        "Date": "Tue, 02 Apr 2019 07:46:24 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "117",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "status": 400,
        "message": "The parameter 'file' has an invalid value 
    '/!FILEPATH/CSV_TEST/test_data.xlsx'."
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try using the `Parse JSON` action from the `Data Operations` connector

Comment: @HariHaran, thanks for your reply. I tried using the `Parse JSON` as you suggested, I'm still getting the same error. I've added an additional error output to the original post.

Comment: The file path that you provided is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug when you used picker but trying to add customized value. I had workaround by using Sharepoint to get Id-Metadata as described from this document and it worked

> The File property expected by the connector's actions should be filled
>   using one of the following options:
>
> Pick a file from the file picker.
>
> Use an output from the OneDrive for Business connector's
>   triggers/actions (file's Id or File identifier property depending on
>   which one is present for the particular OneDrive for Business's action
>   or trigger).
>
> **Use an output from the SharePoint connector's triggers/actions (file's
>   Id or Identifier property depending on which one is present for the
>   particular Sharepoint's action or trigger**).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#known-issues-and-limitations

[image]